# How can I load specific datalist from Sqflite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I have a table 'users' in Sqlite like this.

```
id: 1
name : Nick
age : 26
registered Date : Aug 10

id: 2
name : Summer
age : 21
registered Date : Aug 9

id: 3
name : Emma
age : 24
registered Date : Aug 8
```

If I want to know person who registered on specific date, like Aug 8, how can I handle it? I already have db.dart with DBHelper, and home.dart with FutureBuilder. Is it correct to use rawQuery like this? Please let me know how to load specific fatalist from db.dart to home.dart.

```
Future<void> compare(String Date) async {
     final db = await database
     var results = await db.rawQuery(
      'SELECT * FROM users WHERE $registeredDate =$Date',
    );
}
```

Comment: see once https://stackoverflow.com/a/53634381/8388068

https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b

Comment: @ParthPitroda I've already read this before, but don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do should work, however in this case you can use the SQFlite helper methods the following way:

```
final db = await database;
return await db.query('users', where: '$registeredDate = ?', whereArgs: [Date]);
```

In this case it may seem unnecessary, however, the helper methods help you avoid syntax issues with SQL.

You can get more information on the helper methods by looking at the examples of the package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If there are several people who registered on a specific day, is it possible to load all of the list?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the date with the where clause and you will receive a List<Map<String, dynamic>> with the results. You always receive a List of results unless you specify differently.